# GET json data array within a array in Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium

'This is my JSON messgae. im trying to list item name under the category. Before trying this i just try to print all item name in single window without category in Titanium. But my code is not working.'

```
  {
     "name" : "Nation",
      {.......
   },
   "menus" : [
   {
          "menuId" : 33,
          "menuName": "Breakfast", 
           .........{
          },
         "menuItems": [
          {
          "itemName": "Thrilled Cheese",
                "category": "Entree",
           },
           {
          "itemName": "Today's Soup - Small",
                "category": "Entree",
           },
           {
          "itemName": "Lrg. Fountain Drink",
                "category": "Entree",
           },
           {
          "itemName": "Lemon Juice",
                "category": "Entree",
           },
           ...........}
           ]
        },


       {
          "menuId" : 34,
          "menuName": "Dinner", 
           .........{
          },
         "menuItems": [
          {
          "itemName": "Sweepstakes Entry",
                "category": "Entree",
           },
           {
          "itemName": "Veggie Breakfast Burrito",
                "category": "Entree",
           },
           {
          "itemName": "Sm. Fountain Drink",
                "category": "Drink",
           },
           {
          "itemName": "Med. Fountain Drink",
                "category": "Drink",
           },
           ...........
           ]
         ]
     }
```

'This is my code to print all item name in single window without category '

```
     var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    for (var i = 0; i < json.menus.length; i++) {

        for (var j = 0; j < json.menus[i].menuitems[j].lenght; j++) {  

            var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                height: 60,
            });

            var itemLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                text: json.menus[i].menuItems[j].menuItems.itemName, 
                height: 'auto',
                left:54,
                top: 5,
                font:{ fontSize:20 } 
            });

            row.add(itemLabel);
            data.push(row);

       }
    }

    tableview.setData(data);
```

Comment: better give some link for json data.

Comment: @suchit sorry that's a official restaurant link. without doing that is there any possibilities there?

Comment: I'd put a breakpoint on the for loop and see if your information has been structured into the json variable as you expected.  I'd also put a breakpoint on tableview.setData(data) and look at the data variable to see all the rows it contains.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the second for loop for the length.

```
 for (var j = 0; j < json.menus[i].menuitems[j].lenght; j++) {
```

to

```
 for (var j = 0; j < json.menus[i].menuitems[j].length; j++) {
```

Comment: My code is correct. But the mistake in creating windowform for this tableview page. `var curtWin = Ti.UI.currentWindow;`